# Lombok fluent accessors and thymeleaf th:field error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, lombok

So I have

```
lombok.accessors.fluent=true
lombok.accessors.chain=true
```

in my config, since i don't like writing get/set each time. This results in the following:

```
var client = new Client().name("name").email("email");
var name = client.name();
```

Now, I was able to make thymeleaf recognize this in `th:text`:

`<td th:text="${user.id()}"></td>`

But when I try to populate the fields in the form like so:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{}" th:object="${client}" method="post">
         <input type="text" th:field="*{name}">

<!-- tried this too:    <input type="text" th:field="*{name()}"> -->
</form>
```

I get a
`NotReadablePropertyException: Bean property 'name' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?`

This is due to the fluent flag, which removes the get/set prefix.

Now what I'm trying to do is find a way to fix this issue with leaving the flag as it is and make thymeleaf understand the syntax, is there one?

Generating both fluent and non fluent accessors is not possible in lombok.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.